# Select text occurrences in dom provided by input text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selection, nwjs

I'm trying to build some search engine on my [nwjs](https://nwjs.io/) application and for several reasons, I can't use APIs like [Mark.js](https://markjs.io/) because it causes dom changes wrapping some HTML tag around the word I want to find. That is why I want to use text selection to represent the highlight but I don't know-how.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want this:

- https://github.com/nwutils/find-in-nw

It will also add dom wrappers, but removes them when done.

The only other way I can think of doing what you want would be:

1. Detect the x,y coordinates of text on the page

   - Good luck. Text reflows based on layout and browser width. If the text is not wrapped in an element I'm not sure how to get it's coords or size (bounding box/rect)
2. Create an absolute positioned element above it with a `mix-blend-mode: darken`

   - This would work for dark text on a background lighter than your highlight. So like white text on a black background with a yellow highlight. But if it's white text on a black background you'd need `mix-blend-mode: lighten`. Also, good luck determining the background color and text as those can be stored on basically anywhere in the DOM.

You're better off just using that library, or finding a different way approach or define your problem space.

Comment: I've tried this solution before, but in my opinion, the implementation is really bad. I have found this solution and I guess it works! https://bityli.com/u89WmD. But thank you so much for your time, Jared!